# MVC custom errors/ http errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have been trying to implement custom errors and http errors and unable to make it work

1) i have custom errors in config

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx"  redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ErrorPages/403.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/500.aspx"/>     
    </customErrors>
```

as per my understanding when i will try http://localhost:50753/unmatchedURL
MVC wil generate 404 and from customErrors it will redirect to ~/ErrorPages/404.aspx

It **always redirect to /Error** , i dont know why

2) and my httperrors

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
      <clear/>
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="~/ErrorPages/404.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="~/ErrorPages/500.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

and if i try  http://localhost:50753/unmatchedURL.html it will picked by IIS and IIS will generate 404 and will redirect client to ~/ErrorPages/404.html.

but it also doesnt work and **it returns to always /Error**

and if i try http://localhost:50753/Scripts/app/%27%26%20SET%20%2fA%200xFFF9999-2%20%26/templates/staticheader.html it generates 500
and i get in result

[image]

**Questions:**

1) why it always redirect to /Error where as i have commented  `//filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());`  in filterconfig and not using any where in solution

2) i have to use `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">` because i m sending bad request response in case of code exception

can some one help me why its not working

Comment: This compilation error.

Comment: Do you still need an answer?